# How to name the fields of related model in filter object?

Tags: json, where-clause, loopbackjs

In my project, two models "UserProfile" and "UserAccount" are with a relation that the former "has one" the later. The .json files look like:

userprofile.json:

```
{
  "name": "Userprofile",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  //...
  "properties": {
    "userid": {
      "type": "Number"
    },
    "phoneno": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  //...
  "relations": {
    "userAccounts": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "UserAccount",
      "foreignKey": "id",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

useraccount.json:

```
{
  "name": "UserAccount",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "restrictResetPasswordTokenScope": true,
  "emailVerificationRequired": true,
  "properties": {},
  "relations": {}
  //...
}
```

The models have corresponding tables in a MariaDB.

Now the quest is to "GET" UserProfile with a keyword that match any one field of UserProfile.phoneno **or** UserAccount.email (yes, the key point is **or**). In SQL terms, that is:

```
SELECT * FROM UserProfile INNER JOIN UserAccount 
ON UserProfile.userid = UserAccount.id
WHERE UserProfile.phoneno LIKE '%keyword%'
OR UserAccount.email LIKE '%keyword%'
```

It should be a common and simple query in SQL but seems become difficult in LookBack. My implementation is:

userprofile.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (Userprofile) {
  Userprofile.remoteMethod('profileByEmailOrPhoneno', {
    description: '...',
    http: {path:'/profileByEmailOrPhoneno', verb: 'get'},
    accepts: {arg: 'keyword', type: 'string', required: true},
    returns: {arg: 'profile', type: 'array' } 
  })

  Userprofile.profileByEmailOrPhoneno = function (keyword, cb) {
    let filter = {
      fields: {userid: true, nickname: true, phoneno: true},
      include: {
        relation: 'userAccounts',
        scope: {
          fields: {username: true, email: true}
        }
      },
      where: {or: [
        {phoneno: {like: `%${keyword}%`}}, 
        {'userAccount.email': {like: `%${keyword}%`}}
      ]} 
    }

    Userprofile.find(
      filter,
      function (err, records) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else cb(null, records)
      }
    )
  }
};
```

I tested it on StrongLoop API Explorer and it always returned the whole records in UserProfile no matter whatever keyword. If the criterium

```
{'userAccount.email': {like: `%${keyword}%`}}
```

was removed the codes worked correctly. I think this criterium is wrong so LookBack ignores it and evaluate the where section to be true. I modified it to:

```
{'email': {like: `%${keyword}%`}}
```

and it was still wrong.

So, I wonder how to correctly name the relation model's field (eg.'email'), or, how to write the correct filter. Anybody can give some help? I'll very appreciated for it. ^^

Answer (score 0):

The *include* statement in Loopback is a left-outer-join, so the query will always return ALL the Userprofile records.  Some will have userAccounts with an array of values, other's wont.  You need to further filter the Userprofile records.

Also, you need to put he userAccoutns filter in the **scope** statement of your filter:

```
Userprofile.profileByEmailOrPhoneno = function (keyword, cb) {
  let filter = {
    fields: {userid: true, nickname: true, phoneno: true},
    include: {
      relation: 'userAccounts',
      scope: {
        fields: {username: true, email: true},
        where: {'email':{'like': `%${keyword}%`}} // userAccounts filter goes here
      }
    },
    where: {phoneno: {like: `%${keyword}%`}} 
  }

  Userprofile.find(filter, function (err, records) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else {
      // filter the records for those that have userAccounts
      var filteredResults = records.filter(record => 
        record.userAccounts && 
        Array.isArray(record.userAccounts()) && 
        record.userAccounts().length);
      cb(null, filteredResults)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your instant help. ^^   But, your _filter_ gives the result like `WHERE condition1 AND condition2` , not "OR". Perhaps I should think about refactor the models or tables.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  It looks like you have to either filter your results on the server (get all the values from the db then loop through the results extracting the data you want),  or find a way to save the email information directly in the Userprofile to make the query work, or a 3rd option is to query the database directly with a more complex query and translate the result into loopback models.

My experience with loopback filters is that they are good for simply queries.  Trying to perform an OR on 2 different properties in 2 different tables or collections is too complex.